# vmc tunnel cannot start the client

Tags: cloud-foundry

I cannot tunnel any service on my CloudFoundry (api.vcap.me) installation. The tunelling works fine in api.cloudfoundry.com. I have upgraded ruby and vmc to ruby 1.9.2p290 and vmc 0.3.18 but the problem persists.

I get the same error for both mongodb and mysql. Both clients are in my PATH.

C:>vmc tunnel

1: mongodb-test

2: mysql-test

Which service to tunnel to?: 2
Getting tunnel connection info: OK

Service connection info:
  username : u42J7Gge9HdRW
  password : pUfd7tnVA4Ps8
  name     : d5afd08fb7fe9423f93ae6883a586c847

Starting tunnel to mysql-test on port 10000.
1: none
2: mysql
3: mysqldump
Which client would you like to start?: 2
Launching 'mysql --protocol=TCP --host=localhost --port=10000 --user=u42J7Gge9HdRW --password=pUfd7tnVA4Ps8 d5afd08fb7fe9423f93ae6883a586c847'

**ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
Error: 'mysql' execution failed; is it in your $PATH?**

Comment: I've seen this error reported by someone else, and it turned out to be a proxy issue. Either way it's likely a networking or proxy issue. Instead of running the mysql client after setting up the tunnel, have you tried troubleshooting by using telnet to connect to port 10000? http://sysadmin-e.com/telnet

Comment: Yes, telnet connects successfully to port 10000.
I get the same error from all PCs even from the server where CF is installed.
On my PC the ruby.exe process opens a port on 0.0.0.0:10000 and 127.0.0.1:10000. When I select option 2:mysql it throws the error and the ruby process dies.

Comment: You get a similar error with MongoDB as well? Which is it exactly? Are you able to successfully bind a service to a deployed app and communicate with the service? If not try checking the VCAP logs for clues.

Comment: Same error with MongoDB. Mysql and mongodb services bind successfully to Spring Apps.

C:\>vmc apps
caldecott| 1| RUNNING|caldecott-6139e.vcap.me|mysql-test, mongodb-test
C:\>vmc tunnel mongodb-test --port 9999 mongo
...
connecting to: localhost:9999/db
Wed Jun 27 09:37:34 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Wed Jun 27 09:37:34 Error: Error during mongo startup. :: caused by :: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: localhost:9999 query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } shell/mongo.js:86
exception: connect failed
Error: 'mongo' execution failed; is it in your $PATH?

Comment: I suggest asking for help on the vcap-dev mailing list: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev

Answer (score 1):

A new CloudFoundry server have been installed on a similar machine with Ubuntu 10. Tunelling with cadlecott works OK now. The problem remains on the previous CF server.